# git diff - difference between .. notation and omitting it

Tags: git, git-diff

Is there any difference between this command:

```
git diff --stat HEAD..origin/dev
```

and this command?

```
git diff --stat HEAD origin/dev
```

Comment: @torek once explained to me that with `..` you are forcing git to do more processing, but that the output will be the same.

Comment: yeah thx...hmmm...what is this "more processing" lol?

Comment: @eftshift0: it's more complicated than that. The front end `git diff` *command* has special treatment when the string it hands to the internal rev-parse code produces one of two particular outputs. (Run `git rev-parse A..B` and `git rev-parse A...B` for two valid commits A and B to see.)  If you're doing `git log` with `-p`, `git log` calls the internal diff code, which leads to yet a different series of special cases. It's annoyingly complicated.

Comment: @torek, what's you name? Junio? :-)

Comment: By the way, `...` is extremely useful, in my experience... but it's definitely not the same as `..`.

Comment: @eftshift0: That's a different guy. I've just taken on the job of demystifying Git, which may also be impossible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**For `git diff`**, there is no difference.

**For other commands**, yes, there is a difference.

There is another special `git diff` case: `A...B` means something unusual for `git diff`.

Comment: beware the ellipsis when running git diff!